# What is adb command to list all the browsers installed on android device?

Tags: java, android, adb

I wanted to list all the browser package names from android device

Like (chrome, Mozilla and UC browser )

Is there any generalized adb command ?

Comment: you can list package names

Comment: Need to filter out the browsers any specific regex  we can use ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends on your definition of a `browser`. If it is an app with registered intent filters in the `android.intent.category.APP_BROWSER` category - you can get the list with the following `adb shell` command:

```
for P in $(pm list packages); do test -n "$(dumpsys package ${P#package:} | grep APP_BROWSER)" && echo ${P#package:}; done
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any generalized adb command ?

The short answer is: No

Currently, ADB shell only support its own list of commands available, you just can't filter them into application type such as browser.

**adb shell pm list packages [options]**

List of commands

```
adb shell pm list packages
adb shell pm list packages -f See their associated file.
adb shell pm list packages -d Filter to only show disabled packages.
adb shell pm list packages -e Filter to only show enabled packages.
adb shell pm list packages -s Filter to only show system packages.
adb shell pm list packages -3 Filter to only show third party packages.
adb shell pm list packages -i See the installer for the packages.
adb shell pm list packages -u Also include uninstalled packages.
adb shell pm list packages --user <USER_ID> The user space to query.
```